# Empty media library in first initialization

Tags: swift, swiftui

The media library is empty on first launch. If I open it again, then everything will be fine later. I have media picker provided by `BSImagePicker`.

Why media library is empty in first initialization?

`ContentView.swift`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var isPresentedSheet: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.isPresentedSheet = true
        }) {
            Text("Add media")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$isPresentedSheet, content: {
            ImagePickerCoordinatorView()
        })
    }

}
```

`MediaPicker.swift`:

```
import SwiftUI
import Photos
import BSImagePicker

public struct ImagePickerCoordinatorView {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    private func dismiss() {
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }

}

extension ImagePickerCoordinatorView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    public typealias UIViewControllerType = ImagePickerController

    public func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ImagePickerController {
        let picker = ImagePickerController()
        picker.settings.selection.max = 5
        picker.settings.selection.unselectOnReachingMax = false
        picker.settings.theme.selectionStyle = .numbered
        picker.settings.fetch.assets.supportedMediaTypes = [.image, .video]
        picker.imagePickerDelegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    public func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ImagePickerController, context: Context) {
    }

    public func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

}

extension ImagePickerCoordinatorView {

    public class Coordinator: ImagePickerControllerDelegate {

        private let parent: ImagePickerCoordinatorView

        public init(_ parent: ImagePickerCoordinatorView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        public func imagePicker(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, didSelectAsset asset: PHAsset) {
        }

        public func imagePicker(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, didDeselectAsset asset: PHAsset) {
        }

        public func imagePicker(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, didFinishWithAssets assets: [PHAsset]) {
            print(assets)
            parent.dismiss()
        }

        public func imagePicker(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, didCancelWithAssets assets: [PHAsset]) {
            parent.dismiss()
        }

        public func imagePicker(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, didReachSelectionLimit count: Int) {
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: PLease clearify your question. Like what you want and whats happening

Comment: @Kudos Update my question. Why media library is empty in first initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the issues in the BSImagePicker library, there is an explanation for your specific problem.

https://github.com/mikaoj/BSImagePicker/issues/328

The explanation is:
"If you are using the delegate and presenting the image picker yourself you also need
to request permission to the photo library before presenting the picker."